# When a cold drink is taken from a refrigerator, its temperature is 5°C. After 25 minutes in a 20°C room its temperature has increased to 10°C.

Tags: calculus

When a cold drink is taken from a refrigerator, its temperature is 5°C. After 25 minutes in a 20°C room its temperature has increased to 10°C. (Round your answers to two decimal places.)

(a) What is the temperature of the drink after 40 minutes?

°C

(b) When will its temperature be 15°C?

min

My work is here: I not sure I am doing it right. [image]

Comment: This is more a physical problem than a mathematical. You assumed an exponential law of decay of the temperature. This not exact. The law is more complicated and involves the thermal exchanges by natural convection which is not a simple exponential law and eventually forced convection with is still different. Overall, the thermal losses by evaporation is far to be negligible. This question should be first raised on the physics forum. After defitition of a more correct formula for the temperature decay, the question could eventually comme back to the mathematical forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice, we have $$T=Ce^{kt}+T_s$$
Setting $T=T_0$ (initial temperature of cold drink) at $t=0$ then we have $$T_0=Ce^{0}+T_s\iff C=T_0-T_s$$

Now, we have $$T=(T_0-T_s)e^{kt}+T_s$$ $$e^{kt}=\frac{T-T_s}{T_0-T_s}$$
$$t=\frac{1}{k}\ln\left(\frac{T-T_s}{T_0-T_s}\right)\tag 1$$

Given condition: Temperature rise of cold drink from $\color{red}{T_0=5^\circ \ C\to T=10^\circ \ C}$ in time $t=25\ minutes$ & $\color{red}{T_s=20^\circ \ C}$ substituting values in (1) we get $$25=\frac{1}{k}\ln\left(\frac{10-20}{5-20}\right)$$
$$k=\frac{1}{25}\ln\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)$$

a) Temperature $\color{red}{T}$ after $t=40 \ minutes$, setting corresponding values in (1), we get 
$$40=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{25}\ln\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)}\ln\left(\frac{T-20}{5-20}\right)$$ $$\ln\left(\frac{20-T}{15}\right)=\frac{40}{25}\ln\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)$$ $$\frac{20-T}{15}=\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{8/5}$$
$$\color{red}{T}=20-15\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{8/5}\approx \color{blue}{12.15^\circ\ C}$$

b) Time $\color{red}{t}$ when the temperature is $\color{red}{T=15^\circ C}$, setting corresponding values in (1), we get 
$$t=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{25}\ln\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)}\ln\left(\frac{15-20}{5-20}\right)$$ 
$$=\frac{25 \ln\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)}{\ln\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)}$$

$$\color{red}{t}\approx \color{blue}{67.74\ minutes}$$